# System.Threading.Timer not continuous

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

I am having troubles with creating a continuous timer. There are multipule staggered threads created on timers which will run for some time then come to a complete stop. The maximum threads I am allowing is 5 and the timer interval is set to 10000. So in theory there would be 1 thread executed every 2 seconds.

This happens for a while, but then it stops. currently I am testing in a console app and writing the responses to the app.

I am not exactly sure what is happening here

```
internal class EngineThreadGenerator
{
    private readonly AutoResetEvent _autoEvent;
    private readonly Action<string, string> _processQueueDelegate;
    private readonly Action<string, string> _purgeQueueDelegate;

    private void createAllowedEmailThreads()
    {
        for (int counter = 0; counter < AppSettings.ProcessQueueAllowedThreads; counter++)
        {
            EmailThread _emailThread = new EmailThread(_collection, _processQueueDelegate, _purgeQueueDelegate);
            TimerCallback _timerCallback = _emailThread.InitEmailThread;
            Timer _stateTimer = new Timer(_timerCallback, _autoEvent, 0, AppSettings.ProcessIntervalInMilliseconds);

            pauseLoop();
        }
    }
```

Any help here is greatly appreciated! Cheers!

Comment: Are you saying that the spawning of threads is stopping, or that the threads themselves are stopping? How long is "a while"?

Comment: The Threads themselve, typically they stop 3  minutes into the process.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason your timers are dying after 3 minutes is that you have a lot of memory available.

Which means the garbage collector takes about 3 minutes to get to your objects before collecting them.

You're supposed to keep a reference to the timer for the duration of its lifetime. Since you're not doing that, the timer is eligible for garbage collection as soon as your loop ends.

3 minutes later, or whenever GC gets around to it, the timer is collected, and your code stops executing.

So, keep a reference to the timer object, and you should be all set.

Here's a simple [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net) script to test with:

```
void Main()
{
    new Timer(Callback, null, 0, 1000);
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    Debug.WriteLine("collecting");
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    GC.Collect();
    Debug.WriteLine("collected");
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
}

static void Callback(object state)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("callback");
}
```

Observe that once the main thread runs GC, the callback stops. If, on the other hand, you make a copy of the timer into a field:

```
Timer _Timer;

void Main()
{
    _Timer = new Timer(Callback, null, 0, 1000);
    ...
```

the timer keeps on ticking past GC.

Comment: doh... my build is in a console app as well, that would also explain why wouldn't it?

Comment: Depends, does your console application hang around until the threads are supposed to be done? If it does, or at least is supposed to, then there's nothing wrong with using a console application for this, just don't let the main thread (aka, Program.Main), exit. When it does, all the references in china won't keep your timers alive.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance! How do I keep that main thread running?

Comment: Well, how long does it need to keep running? If indefinitely, just set up a ManualResetEvent, and wait on it, just never signal it. If you're waiting for something, still use a ManualResetEvent, wait on it, but signal it when that something comes around. Having said that, if you're building a piece of program that is assumed to be running all the time, you really should consider building a proper windows service instead.

Comment: The intent is to build a WindowsService, I just created the console for testing purposes. I will look at the ManualResetEvent. Thank you, Threading is fairly new to me!

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen thank you. Not only is the information you've given helpful but it's also educational. Can't thank you enough!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it just isn't in this code snippit, but do you ever decrement `counter`?

Comment: Wow, a downvote? For what? The original code snipit would just loop a couple times then exit, which could explain why it works for 'a while' then stops.

Comment: If I did, it was purley by accident

Comment: No I don't decrement the counter, the coutner is only to iterate through the loop and create timer threads. so if I have max of 5 then only five timer threads should be created.

Comment: I also just tested the timer without the looping, so a single thread is created and still stops